# Using Monte Carlo simulations with subsequent element removal

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, experiment-design, monte-carlo

I'm attempting to build an evaluation set for a logistic regression classifier and I've run into a statistical problem.

The study involves a very large population (G) that has two properties of interest, a True/False property (P) and an numeric field (Q). These two fields are not independent.

So far I have collected:
X, a representative sample of the elements of G for which P = True. 
Y, a non representative group from G with a bias towards P being True. (size > size of evaluation set)

I'm attempting to make a group of *m* items out of Y that has similar properties to X via the method. However having run the Monte Carlo method I then remove all the elements with P = False (this is only possible for small groups as this identification is manual and time consuming).  This changes the distribution of Q so that it is no longer similar to X.

Is there a clever way of avoiding this problem (or a sensible iterative method to keep things quick?)

Thank you for your help, and obviously I'm happy to answer questions/queries in the comments.

EDIT:
Summary - 
I'm trying to create a group of rare objects (P=true) within the population. Testing P accurately is very slow so I created Y, a group for which P = True is quite common. I then use a Monte Carlo simulation to reduce the size of Y and match it's the properties to X. I then remove the P = False items (which have statistically lower values of Q). Now my evaluation group is not representative (we've biased Q upwards). Is there a sensible way to work around this?

Comment: Could you possibly go into more details? From your description it is not perfectly clear what do you mean.

Comment: Edited the question to provide more details